# Service mysql not runnig Dockerfile

Tags: mysql, docker, dockerfile

I have from issue running mysql using Dockerfile

```
FROM mysql:latest

# Add a database
ENV MYSQL_DATABASE some_table_name
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD some_password
ADD some_table.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
ENTRYPOINT /bin/bash
```

Building an image works for this code but mysql service is not found in the container when I try to run service mysql start. mysqld command would not run due to some root security issues. Is anyone able to help? Thank you.

Comment: you can't run `service/systemctl mysql start` inside a container. What are you trying to achieve with the `ENTRYPOINT /bin/bash`? Because that is the bit that starts mysqld in the default mysql:latest container.

Comment: I want to enter the container to check if the password I set does work and also to check if the table I added is indeed inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `ENTRYPOINT`

build and run the container.

Run another process to check inside the container name like:

```
docker exec -ti {containername} mysql -u root -p
```

This will check the password is set right. Then `SHOW CREATE TABLE {db.tablename}`

Comment: Wow thanks, that worked! By any chance do you have any resources that you would recommend to pick up Docker?